# How to define a function on a struct pointer in assembly?

Tags: assembly, go

For example:

```
// dummy.go
type dummy struct {
    p uintptr
}

func (d dummy) Get(i int) uint64
//func (d *dummy) Get(i int) uint64 //no way to define *dummy in assembly
```

`func (d dummy) Get` can be defined as:

```
// dummy_amd64.s
#include "textflag.h"
TEXT ·dummy·Get(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    MOVQ $42, 24(SP)
    RET
```

I tried

```
TEXT "".(*dummy).Get+0(SB),4,$0-24 //output from 6g -S
TEXT ""·(*dummy)·Get+0(SB),4,$0
TEXT ·*dummy·Get(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
//and
TEXT ·(*dummy)·Get(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
```

All of them gives me the same error:

> syntax error, last name: "".

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Try to define the function in the programming language you are using (go, as far as I see) and to disassemble the object file. Then you see the "real" function name. For example in C++ "myClass::myFunc(int,int)" may be named _Z7myClassF6myFuncII in assembler.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Sadly copy/pasting the output doesn't work, I forgot to include that in the question.

Comment: I found nada grepping the `TEXT` clauses in the stdlib. Worth a golang-nuts post--wonder if it's even possible.

Comment: @twotwotwo Yeah I spent few hours doing that, ended up not needing it, I just wanted to know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @MartinRosenau https://github.com/OneOfOne/reallyunsafe/blob/master/reader.go mainly, using it to replace https://github.com/OneOfOne/xxhash/blob/master/native/xxhash_unsafe.go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not possible with the current toolchain. The context is explained in [issue 4978](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4978&q=inline%20assembly%20method&colspec=ID%20Status%20Stars%20Release%20Owner%20Repo%20Summary)

Note that there is [a simple patch](https://codereview.appspot.com/7492043) to enable this feature - but only a few people are using it.

You could write a normal assembly function (i.e. not method), and implement a call in the Go method, to this assembly function. But the extra call will not be optimized away by the compiler.

A possible workaround to this problem would be to implement some support to allow assembly functions to be inlined in Go code - which would bring more benefits. My understanding is it has been discussed in the past, but it is not planned yet.

Comment: That's a great catch, I googled for few hours and I couldn't find that issue.